# Firebase multiple filter query in iOS swift 3x

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am are working on firebase with iOS swift 3 application. And I don't find a good documentation about where like queries in firebase official doc. Following are the criteria to be filter user data from the all user tree.

**My firebase tree:**

[image]

Following is the filter screen that needs to be applied on one query to fetch user by query.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me the things or logic how to perform that kind of query. I know there is sortBy method but that perform only one filter at a time. Kindly suggest something.

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on one property. In some cases you may be able to combine the values you want to order/filter on into a single property (see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)). But even that can only support a single range condition. Since you have two range conditions in your UI, I expect the query won't be possible on Firebase.